# High disk dsage in Bootcamped iMac after repairing the drivers

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, driver

I force closed my iMac for a specific reason (Thunderstorm) and when I restarted it my iMac started to scan and repair its drivers. I waited for 4 hours and everything was fine, until I realized that every app was slow (too many not responding errors).

I restarted my iMac then it again scanned and repaired its drivers for an hour. When I went to the task manager I realized that the disk usage was 100 percent and I couldn't change it.

How can I fix this problem? Will switching back to Mac OS X or formatting the Windows partition fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I know it can be frustrating when you're trying to solve an issue, but it's vital that you give us enough info to help you. As the question is written, it seems we're missing some key details. Perhaps you can clarify the following: (1) Can you confirm that when you say *"my iMac started to scan and repair its drivers"* and *"every app was slow"* that you're referring to being booted into Windows? (2) Assuming that you *are* talking about Windows, what happens if you boot into macOS? Do things work normally or do you also have problems?

Comment: I deleted my booted windows, reinstalling right now.